# SetTimeOut for script and inline script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, settimeout

There is a map from 2gis that first loads an external script, and then the map widget is loaded in the inline script (if I understand everything correctly). Need to delay loading the script and run inline script only after loading the main script.

```
<script src="https://widgets.2gis.com/js/DGWidgetLoader.js"></script>

<script>new DGWidgetLoader({"width":640,"height":600,"borderColor":"#a3a3a3","pos":{"lat":52.291708811505536,"lon":104.33831691741945,"zoom":16},"opt":{"city":"irkutsk"},"org":[{"id":"1548640653330917"}]});</script>
```

I have already tried different options, including the one below, but an error occurs in the closing `</script>` tag.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem = document.createElement('script');
    elem.src = 'https://widgets.2gis.com/js/DGWidgetLoader.js';
    elem.onload = function() {
      document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('scroll'))
    }
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
  }, 2000);
}, false);

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery("#2gismaps").append('<script>new DGWidgetLoader({"width":640,"height":600,"borderColor":"#a3a3a3","pos":{"lat":52.291708811505536,"lon":104.33831691741945,"zoom":16},"opt":{"city":"irkutsk"},"org":[{"id":"1548640653330917"}]});</script>');
  }, 3000);
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="2gismaps" style="width: 100%; height: 420px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to output JavaScript in the HTML to run it. You can run your JavaScript in the `onload` handler after the script has loaded. The `onload` method gives you control to execute something exactly after it has finished loading.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://widgets.2gis.com/js/DGWidgetLoader.js';
  script.onload = function() {
    // The script has now loaded, so you can call the DGWidgetLoader loader.
    new DGWidgetLoader({
      "width":640,
      "height":600,
      "borderColor":"#a3a3a3",
      "pos": {
        "lat":52.291708811505536,
        "lon":104.33831691741945,
        "zoom":16
      },
      "opt": {
        "city":"irkutsk"
      },
      "org": [
        {
          "id":"1548640653330917"
        }
      ]
    });
  }
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}, false);
```